# C# static nullable check membernotnullwhen still shows warning even when check should pass

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have the following code

```
            private PreCtScan? _scan;

            [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(_scan))]
            public bool IsSuccess() {
                return _scan != null && _modelState.IsValid;
            }
            
            public PreCtScan? GetPreCtScanObj() {
                if (_scan != null) {
                    _scan.FormAccumulator = _formAccumulator;
                }
                
                return _scan;
            }
```

But when I call the IsSuccess method i still get a warning that i might be converting a nullable object to a non nullable

```
           if (!builder.IsSuccess()) {
               return BadRequest(builder.GetErrors());
           }

           PreCtScan preCtScanObj = builder.GetPreCtScanObj();
```

[image]
Is there anything i have missed here since having read other answers it appears am doing this correctly.

Comment: When analysing `PreCtScan preCtScanObj = builder.GetPreCtScanObj();`, the compiler doesn't take into account that `GetPreCtScanObj` returns `_scan`, because that is an implementation detail. Ideally, you would establish a connection between `GetPreCtScanObj` and `IsSuccess`, but there aren't attributes to do that.

Comment: Ah i see so this would only work if i would access _scan via a getter property then?

Comment: The short answer is that the analysis is not as advanced as you wish it was. When it looks at the `GetPreCtScanObj` call, it doesn't beforehand look into the `IsSuccess` call to verify anything. That, plus _even if it did_ it wouldn't be reliable - since nothing would stop another thread altering the value of `_scan` between the two calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's read the following line:

```
PreCtScan preCtScanObj = builder.GetPreCtScanObj();
```

`builder.GetPreCtScanObj()` this will return the `PreCtScan?` type which **IS** nullable and thus different from the `PreCtScan` type, so a conversion is in order.

If there was no issue, then `GetPreCtScanObj` could return the `PreCtScan` type.

So the real question is why `GetPreCtScanObj` can't return `PreCtScan` instead of `PreCtScan?`. From your code it is clear that it very well can return null as we can see from the `return _scan;` line.

Comment: I would say because GetPreCtScanObj can be called without calling the IsSuccess function, and i would like to avoid throwing an exception if that was the case as that would have exceptions dictating the flow of the application. What i want is the compiler to know that if IsSuccess has been called before GetPreCtScanObj and has returned success that will not be nullable.

Comment: @Harry You can't have both, alas. You have to pick your poison. You can't say it is returning nullable, then complain when the compiler rightly complains about that.

Comment: Then as you can see the warning is indeed valid. You can return a null value

Comment: Fair enough, thanks both i wish there was a way for C# to mark the correlation of the function between the property. I will mark this as correct as it solves my question.